# REST API endpoint with roles-restricted fields

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, crud, endpoint

Need your advice with my project as I am currently stuck with one issue.

I have an endpoint **api/v1/groups/:id** from which a logged-in User can get info about particular group. And there are two possible replies which the User can **GET**:

1. {
   id: 'groupId',
   name: 'groupName',
   description: 'groupDescription',
   isAccessApproved: bool
   }

**isAccessApproved** - is a boolean value which indicates whether users access to join the group was approved or not

2. In case user haven't sent a request to join the group, he will get a reply that group with this ID is not found.

However, I was asked for Admin and Super Admin to get all info about the particular group even if they haven't sent the request to join the group.

So the main issue is that if I will add Roles checks on **api/v1/groups/:id** endpoint for Admin and Super Admin Roles, I will get if checks inside the method and two different types of JSON object which can be returned from this endpoint: the one **with isAccessApproved field which is bool value** and the other JSON object will not contain this key, because it's useless to send it, they haven't sent a request to join the group and they don't need it at all. And this situation confuses me a lot. From what I read here on stack, the following solutions are possible:

1. **api/v1/groups/:id** which will return JSON object to Admin and Super Admin with full info about the particular group without isAccessApproved. For all other users who sent a request to join the group, api/v1/groups/:id will return JSON with isAccessApproved bool value.
2. Create **api/v1/admin/groups/:id** which will be used by Super Admin and Admin. Still not sure whether it will ok for it to be used by both Admin and Super Admin, as far as Super Admin will have more rights in the application
3. Admin and Super Admin will be requesting a group from the **api/v1/groups/:id** , however some sort of middleware will define whether it's Admin/Super Admin requests the source and will forward the request to the **api/v1/admin/groups/:id** (for example).
4. I don't know. Maybe some separate endpoint like **api/v1/groups/:id/admin** ?????

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I will choose to use the second method. Create a specified endpoint to handle the request at the same permission level is much more clearer and simpler then handle the request at the different permission levels in the same endpoint. You can add `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Super Admin")]` attribute on this specified endpoint, This attribute will only allow user with `Admin` or `Super Admin` role can access this endpoint. `Super Admin` may have more rights in your application, But in this endpoint, `Super Admin` and `Admin` have the same rights to get the data.

The third method is also a good method, But maybe you need to write a middleware to check user's role then rewrite the request path.